# Firefox not able to verify website cirtificate

Tags: firefox, hosting, ssl

I have a website hosted in my dedicated server. When I am now trying to access my website(in firefox) its saying **This Connection is Untrusted** .

[image]
Do I need to change something in my source code or I should ask hosting company about it ?

Comment: For fixing the issue, you might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a secure (https) site without a valid certificate. You need to get a valid certificate (chat to your hosting company about that) or not use HTTPS.

Comment: even by only htttp also its not coming

Comment: Your server is probably re-directing HTTP to HTTPS. It could also be that your machine is compromised or proxied (ie. going through a business proxy) with an untrusted certificate. However this would probably affect more websites than just yours.

Comment: So I should contact hosting company to provide me Certificate for the server ?

Comment: You should contact your hosting company to see how to proceed. They're probably used to requests like this. Often with shared hosting the hosting company needs to be involved in the process of creating + adding SSL certificates.